# Unable to access descendant of an HTML element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with getting a `html()` value of child of a parent :D

```js
function voteup(e){
  var count = $(e).parents('.item').children('.count');
  console.log(count.html()); // undefined
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post_contain">
  <img src="images/comments/dQ6dz.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <p class="post-meta">
    <span href="/gag/agVzE1g" target="_blank">
      <span class="count">5</span>points
    </span>
  </p>
  <div class="vote">
    <ul class="btn-vote left">
      <li class="badge-item-vote-up-li">
        <a onclick="voteup(this)">Click me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the function `voteup(e)`, I need to get the value of the class 'count', but I don't retrieve the value with `html()`

Comment: Please provide the declaration of `voteup`

Comment: This question title has such a different meaning when coming across it from [Parenting.SE](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Wow thank you for the edit ... English is not my mother tongue, i'm sorry :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) only traverses a single level of the DOM tree - i.e. it won't find grandchildren.

Instead, use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the `.item` -- which finds the single nearest match, as opposed to `parents` which can find multiple -- and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to locate the child, since that will traverse arbitrarily deep HTML structures:

```
function voteup(e){
    var count = $(e).closest('.item').find('.count');
    alert(count.html());
    var actual = parseInt(count.html(), 10);
    count.text(actual + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'm a beginner in JQuery and JS :)